# Convert integer to decimal and recover places after zero

Tags: python

I have array data as below:

```
a = np.array([1.41607, 2.17922, -14.7047, -1852.51, -2713.39, -165.025])
```

`a` is a decimal number and I want to convert `a` to an integer number such as below:

```
a = [1, 2, -15, -1853, -2713, -165]
```

then after I convert `a` to an integer number, I want to restore the original data. I have tried using the code below, but I can't restore data to the original data.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1.41607, 2.17922, -14.7047, -1852.51, -2713.39, -165.025])

# Define the number of decimal places to keep
decimal_places = 0

# Round the values to the specified number of decimal places
rounded_a = np.round(a, decimals=decimal_places)

# Convert the rounded values to integers
int_a = (rounded_a * 10**decimal_places).astype(int)

# Convert the integers back to the original decimal values
float_a = int_a / 10**decimal_places

# Print the original values and the recovered values
print("Original values:", a)
print("DecimalToInteger:", int_a)
print("Restored values:", float_a)
```

Results

```
Original values: [    1.41607     2.17922   -14.7047  -1852.51    -2713.39     -165.025  ]
DecimalToInteger: [    1     2   -15 -1853 -2713  -165]
Restored values: [    1.     2.   -15. -1853. -2713.  -165.]
```

Comment: Once you convert to an integer you loose data (an integer has fewer bits than a float). There's no way to convert it back to the original value.

Comment: is there no solution for my case?

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: It's not so much that ints have "fewer bits" than floats, because that's not always the case in Numpy (`float32` vs `int64`, for example), or they can be an equal length. The problem is that you are *losing information* (all the digits past the decimal) when you round to an int, and you simply can't get that information back. It has nothing to do with the *length* of the stored number.

Comment: @stackoffer Does my answer below answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible. Once you convert a float to an integer, there is no going back. You can convert the integer back into a float, but you won't get back any of the decimal places you had before.

This is because you're using a function that loses information. In your case, you used `np.round()`. `np.round()` tells the computer to round the number to the closest integer, then throw away all the information left in the places after the decimal point. Because you threw it away, there's no getting it back.